# Laravel help for optimize command script

Tags: laravel, optimization

I'm working with Lumen framework v5.8 (it's the same as Laravel)

I have a command for read a big XML (400Mo) and update datas in database from datas in this file, this is my code :

```
public function handle()
{
    $reader = new XMLReader();
    $reader->open(storage_path('app/mesh2019.xml'));

    while ($reader->read()) {
        switch ($reader->nodeType) {
            case (XMLREADER::ELEMENT):
                if ($reader->localName === 'DescriptorRecord') {
                    $node = new SimpleXMLElement($reader->readOuterXML());
                    $meshId = $node->DescriptorUI;
                    $name = (string) $node->DescriptorName->String;

                    $conditionId = Condition::where('mesh_id', $meshId)->first();

                    if ($conditionId) {
                        ConditionTranslation::where(['condition_id' => $conditionId->id, 'locale' => 'fr'])->update(['name' => $name]);
                        $this->info(memory_get_usage());
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

So, I have to find in the XML each `DescriptorUI` element, the value corresponds to the `mesh_id` attribute of my class `Condition`.

So, with `$conditionId = Condition::where('mesh_id', $meshId)->first();` I get the Condition object.

After that, I need to update a child of `Condition` => `ConditionTranslation`. So I just get the element `DescriptorName` and update the `name` field of `ConditionTranslation`

At the end of the script, you can see `$this->info(memory_get_usage());`, and when I run the command the value increases each time until the script runs very very slowly...and never ends.

How can I optimize this script ?

Thanks !

Edit : Is there a way with Laravel for preupdate multiple object, and save just one time at the end all objects ? Like the `flush()` method of Symfony

Comment: Can you try deleting the node `$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);`, after if block and see what happens?

Comment: Can't use parentNode from $node.

Comment: Oh! `unset($node)`?

Comment: Already tried to unset or set to null all variables, but no effect

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

```php
public function handle()
    {
        $reader = new XMLReader();
        $reader->open(storage_path('app/mesh2019.xml'));

        $keyValues = [];
        while ($reader->read()) {
            switch ($reader->nodeType) {
                case (XMLREADER::ELEMENT):
                    if ($reader->localName === 'DescriptorRecord') {
                        $node = new SimpleXMLElement($reader->readOuterXML());
                        $meshId = $node->DescriptorUI;
                        $name = (string) $node->DescriptorName->String;

                        $conditionId = Condition::where('mesh_id', $meshId)->value('id');

                        if ($conditionId) {
                            $keyValues[] = "($conditionId, '".str_replace("'","\'",$name)."')";
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        if (count($keyValues)) {
            \DB::query('INSERT into `conditions` (id, name) VALUES '.implode(', ', $keyValues).' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name)');
        }
    }
```